# Posting graphite events to Hosted Graphite

Tags: graphite, grafana

I'm using [Hosted Graphite](http://hostedgraphite.com) and trying to add deploy events to my grafana dashboard. I first attempted to use the method described [here](https://codeascraft.com/2010/12/08/track-every-release/).

The metric is added to graphite with a simple line at the end of the deploy script:

```
echo "$HOSTEDGRAPHITE_API_KEY.events.$ENVIRONMENT.api.deploy 1" \
  | nc -uw0 carbon.hostedgraphite.com 2003
```

I can show those data points in a simple graph, but using the [annotations feature](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/annotations/) with the "regular metric query" doesn't seem to be adding anything to the graphs.

I'm more interested in using *real* events, based on: http://obfuscurity.com/2014/01/Graphite-Tip-A-Better-Way-to-Store-Events. This should allow us to tag the event with, for example, the commit hash or git tag. Unfortunately, I can't find anything in the [Hosted Graphite documentation](http://docs.hostedgraphite.com/) about how to get these data into graphite. I also can't find anything about it in the [graphite docs](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

Despite the lack of docs, I tried posting to a few endpoints, just hoping to get lucky. All of these returned 404:

```
https://${HOSTEDGRAPHITE_API_KEY}@www.hostedgraphite.com/api/v1/events
https://${HOSTEDGRAPHITE_API_KEY}@www.hostedgraphite.com/api/v1/sink/events
https://${HOSTEDGRAPHITE_API_KEY}@www.hostedgraphite.com/XXXXXX/graphite/events
```

where `XXXXXX` is the path prefix I have when accessing the graphite dashboard at `/XXXXXX/graphite/dashboard`.

I also tried contacting Hosted Graphite support but the "Support" link seems to go nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hosted Graphite employee here.

UPDATE: We support Graphite Events and Annotations now: http://docs.hostedgraphite.com/advanced/annotations-and-events.html

<strike>We don't currently support events, but it is in development.
This is the reason there is no mention of this functionality in our documentation.</strike> 
We do support annotations based on metrics.

Which support link didn't work for you? I'll get that fixed :)

You can email us at support+so@ or on twitter, as you already discovered.

I'm sorry I don't have a better solution to tagging deploys right now ( it's something we want to be able to do too) but it should be available soon.

Please get in touch via email if there's anything else we can help with.

e

EDIT: We're using Intercom for support, do you have something like noscript/disconnect that might stop that from working?

Comment: Yep, I'm running Disconnect, so that would explain it. I'll disable that to work on the problem with annotations based on metrics.

Comment: I'm glad that fixed it. We'll have a think about how we can provide a working link for people when intercom isn't available :)